# Highlight a cell if it falls between 2 values on the worksheet AND text in another cell is x

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet set up with dates that an area is booked for, and a calendar set up on the same sheet. Currently I've got it highlighting the date on the calendar if the date and location match the data from the worksheet (column N has a start date and column O has an end date, location in column T)

It highlights different colours depending on status of confirmed, prov or cancelled (as per https://ibb.co/HzFvQ5P)

The problem I now have is that if a date is cancelled and highlights red, if it is subsequently booked then it won't highlight yellow to show this. Any ideas? (For example in the linked photo the cancelled date on 10th has since been booked so should show as yellow).

I'd have thought that having the cancelled part last on the confirmed/ prov/ cancelled part would mean that the others would take priority, but that doesn't seem to be the case?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A9")) Is Nothing Or Not Intersect(Target, Range("A10")) Is Nothing Then
Dim cell As Range
Dim mrng As Range
Dim loc As Range
Dim rcount As Long
Set mrng = Range("B9:H14")
Set loc = Range("A10")
rcount = Cells(2, "N").End(xlDown).Row
    mrng.Interior.Color = xlNone
    mrng.Borders.LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlLineStyleNone
    For Each cell In mrng
        For x = 2 To rcount

            If Cells(x, "T") = loc And Cells(x, "J") = "CONFIRMED" And cell >= Cells(x, "N") And cell <= Cells(x, "O") Then
                cell.Interior.Color = vbYellow
            End If

            If Cells(x, "T") = loc And Cells(x, "J") = "PROV" And cell >= Cells(x, "N") And cell <= Cells(x, "O") Then
                cell.Interior.Color = vbGreen
            End If

            If Cells(x, "T") = loc And Cells(x, "J") = "CANCELLED" And cell >= Cells(x, "N") And cell <= Cells(x, "O") Then
                cell.Interior.Color = vbRed
            End If

        Next x
    If cell = Date Then cell.BorderAround ColorIndex:=5, Weight:=xlMedium
    Next cell
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Presumably one of your conditions is not met. Hard for us to check.

Comment: The conditions are met, if I change the cancelled date to confirmed it highlights yellow as it should, but when the cancelled date is then confirmed on another entry it remains red.

Comment: Set a breakpoint so that you can see what's happening. Your code should remove all colour. Also for each cell you are doing an inner loop so perhaps a setting is being overwritten.